# Browserify includes my module multiple times

Tags: browserify

I've got the following module structure:

- B depends on A
- C depends on both B and A

Each of A, B, C are separate github repositories, and are loaded into node_modules via npm install.

A browserify build of C puts Module A into the output file twice.

Has anyone seen this, or have ideas on workarounds for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Getting bitten by the same thing and surprised this has no answers, isn't the whole point of browserify to fix this problem?